# How to set my module block to access from anywhere

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Ok, i have custom module, which works as i wish it to work on a url `www.mysite.com/mymodule`. Now i want my module to be accessible with a block name from anylayout, also what do i have to do to embed on the CMS pages as well.

My working module layout (mymodule.xml)

```
<layout version="1.0">
<default>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="...>
                     //js and css added here;
            </action>
    </reference>
</default>
<mymodule_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="mymodule" template="mycorp/mymodule/default.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
</mymodule_index_index>
```

This is my layout for the module. Now suppose i want to access it on other layout handle suppose here

`<catalog_category_default>...<reference name="content">HERE</reference>...</catalog_category_default>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your in `content` just like below. now your block will show before category content.

```
<catalog_category_default><reference name="content"><block type="core/template" name="mymodule" name="mymodule" before="-" template="mycorp/mymodule/default.phtml"></block></reference></catalog_category_default>
```

you can directly call the block in `cms`

```
{{block type="core/template" template="mycorp/mymodule/default.phtml"}}
```

Comment: And what do i need to get this from cms pages ? widgets ?

Comment: update the answer ...